# Rails - Can you round number_to_human_size or specify decimals

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a line to display the file size of an attachment:

```
<%= number_to_human_size(@document.doc_file_file_size) %>
```

However, it gives results like:

> 194 KB
>   84.7 KB
>    194 KB
>   84.4 KB

I'd like to display the numbers using number_to_human_size but either not show any decimals or show the same number of decimal places for all items.  Readability is a bit more important for me in this case than absolute accuracy.

I tried adding .round to the end of the statement but that threw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the docs for [number_to_human_size](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human)

Change `:precision`

```
number_to_human_size(@document.doc_file_file_size, precision: 0)
```